# Get the title or section format

Tags: formatting, section-titles

I want to make a book of abstracts and would like to set the abstract titles with the format of sections (for example). How do I get the format of the section to make random text look like it later, without being a section itself?

I would like something like this (although I am open to other suggestions, too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Real title of the whole thing}
\author{Me (or whoever)}
\date{May 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A real section}

 Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\section{Abstracts}

    \format_as_if_section{Title of abstract 1}


 Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

    \format_as_if_section{Title of abstract 2}


 Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just use `\section{Title of first abstract}` ?

Comment: @PeterWilson I don't want it to be in the TOC or get numbers. I only want the font format

Comment: The font of the sections in `article` class is `\normalfont\Large\bfseries`. You can define your own command with: `\newcommand{\myabstract}[1]{\bigskip\noindent\textbf{\Large#1}\bigskip}` to use as `\myabstract{Title of abstract 1}`. You can change `\bigskip`, for example, with `\vspace{1cm}`

Comment: @Ivan Great, thank you! Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Luis Then use `\section*` which sets nu numbers and adds nothing to the ToC.

Comment: @PeterWilson Also true thank you, good idea. Still, I wanted to obtain the format. But yes, you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `article` class the font of the section title is equivalent to `\normalfont\Large\bfseries`. In the following example I have defined two similar commands. The second one sets the same vertical spacing of `\section`. If you like the indentation after the command, remove `\NoIndentAfterThis`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{noindentafter}

\newcommand{\myabstract}[1]{%
    \bigskip
      \noindent\textbf{\Large#1}
    \bigskip
    \NoIndentAfterThis
}

\newcommand{\myabstractX}[1]{%
    \vspace{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}
      \noindent\textbf{\Large#1}
    \vspace{2.3 ex plus .2ex}
    \NoIndentAfterThis
}

\begin{document}

\section{A real section}

 Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

 Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\section{Abstracts}

\myabstract{Title of abstract 1}

 Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bla

\myabstractX{Title of abstract 2}

 Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]